# Totally flummoxed with "No NgModule Metadata found for..." issue with angular build

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, ng-modules

There's quite a few instances of this error out there on the web so I hope I'm not being too redundant. Alas, they all seem to end up with different issues needing to be resolved to fix it. At this time, I'm trying to narrow down where I should be looking. The scenario is that when attempting to run one particular local app, I end up with this error:

```
ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'ourLazyModule'.
```

(ourLazyModule = not the actual module, but just a stand in for the particular module we are having an issue with).

What's confusing is that this:

- is only happening to me (other devs are running it just fine)
- only happens with one app (I can run our other applications just fine)
- doesn't happen with any one branch (regardless of the branch, I get this error...even from master)
- No amount of clearing my cache resolves it
- completely blowing away my local repo and cloning fresh does not resolve it.

Does any of the above information help narrow down what I should be looking for in terms of why this is happening on my machine? For the record, I'm running OSX. And I have had this app running just fine in the past. So something, somewhere, happened recently and I'm just not sure where to look.

Comment: delete node_modules and dist folder, and run npm install and build it again.

Comment: Delete the Node modules folder, delete the build folders, clean package-lock, re-install (npm i), than serve/build.

Comment: @alt255 no dist folder (I assume because it never fully builds in the first place)

Comment: @LppEdd yep. Tried that several times. Same issue.

Comment: @DA. could you hard reset a new branch step by step and try it out?

Comment: @LppEdd I can completely delete my entire local repo, re-clone fresh, pull any branch (typically master, but this happens with any) and I end up with the same result. It's very weird.

Comment: @DA. I have really no idea then!

Comment: @LppEdd that's OK. Thanks for trying! We're all stumped here too. :)

Comment: @DA. check if you have conflicting packages. I had problems with multiple versions of Webpack recently for example. Try running npm dedupe and reinstalling.
Another thing might be a broken Node installation (?)